# JavaScript Static variable doesn't get set

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I created the following JavaScript class:

```
class projectController{

    static _projectId;

    constructor() {

        this.projectRepository = new projectRepository();

        $.get("views/projectList.html")
            .done((htmlData) => this.setup(htmlData))
            .fail(() => this.error());
    }


    setup(htmlData) {
        this.projectView = $(htmlData);
        $(".content").empty().append(this.projectView );
        this.getData();
    }

    async getData() {
        const projects = await this.projectRepository.getAll();
        $("#projectTemplate").tmpl(projects).appendTo("#projectListContent");


        // ADD ONCLICK EVENT ON PROJECTS
        const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("project");
        for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
            elements[i].onclick = function (e) {
                projectId = e.path[1].id;
                app.loadController("project_details");
            }
        }
    }

    error() {
        $(".content").html("faild to load ");
    }


    static get projectId() {
        return this._projectId;
    }


    static set projectId(value) {
        this._projectId = value;
    }
}
```

Now everything works like it should, except that the projectId doesn't change with this line: `this.projectId = e.path[1].id;`. The value of `e.path[1].id` is 12, so I was expecting the value 12 when I use: `const projectId = projectController.projectId;` in a different class.

Why doesn't the value of projectId change?

Comment: Static properties are indetical for all object instances. That is the base idea of static properties and methods. Maybe look up any code documentation on static properties again for a better understanding. I am not too familiar with class properties in js as I don't use them due to browser support, but you should never change static properties on `this` instance in any language. And I assume JS simply does not allow that to be done.

Comment: From [MDN documentation on static members](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#calling_static_members_from_a_class_constructor_and_other_methods), "static members are not directly accessible using the `this` keyword from non-static methods."

Comment: I added getters and setters in the code, but that's also not working. How can I set the static variable then?

Comment: You need to call them using the class name.